# iOS: How can I create a backup copy of my core data base? And how to export/import that copy?

Tags: ios, core-data, backup

I want to offer the users of my app the possibility to create a backup of the core data database, especially in case he switches to a new device etc.

How would I do that? Especially how can I reimport that file? I mean let's say he makes a backup copy of the database, then changes a ton of stuff and wants to reset to the previous saved backup copy. How would I do that?

Thx!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this sample app, it includes functions for making backups, copying backups to and from iCloud, emailing backups and importing backups from email.
http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

BTW it's much safer to use migratePersistentStore API to make/import backups if your are doing so to and from ICloud.  Also be aware that the sample app assumes you are not using WAL mode which is the default mode for iOS 7. WAL mode uses multiple files which all need to be backed up or copied.

Here is a link to a video demonstrating the sample Apps backup and restore capabilities.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/sample-apps-explanations/backup-files/

Here are the methods used to create copies for backup.  Note that it is possible to open the store with multiple persistentStoreCoordinators so no need to close it down while you make a backup.  Restoring it does obviously require the existing store to be removed first.  Note that there is little difference between the two methods below except that the source store is opened with or without iCloud options.

```
    /*! Creates a backup of the ICloud store

     @return Returns YES of file was migrated or NO if not.
     */
    - (bool)backupICloudStore {
        FLOG(@"backupICloudStore called");


        // Lets use the existing PSC
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *migrationPSC = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];

        // Open the store
        id sourceStore = [migrationPSC addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[self icloudStoreURL] options:[self icloudStoreOptions] error:nil];

        if (!sourceStore) {

            FLOG(@" failed to add old store");
            migrationPSC = nil;
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            FLOG(@" Successfully added store to migrate");

            NSError *error;

            FLOG(@" About to migrate the store...");
            id migrationSuccess = [migrationPSC migratePersistentStore:sourceStore toURL:[self backupStoreURL] options:[self localStoreOptions] withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

            if (migrationSuccess) {
                FLOG(@"store successfully backed up");
                migrationPSC = nil;
                // Now reset the backup preference
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:_makeBackupPreferenceKey];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                return TRUE;
            }
            else {
                FLOG(@"Failed to backup store: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                migrationPSC = nil;
                return FALSE;
            }

        }
        migrationPSC = nil;
        return FALSE;
    }
    /*! Creates a backup of the Local store

     @return Returns YES of file was migrated or NO if not.
     */
    - (bool)backupLocalStore {
        FLOG(@"backupLocalStore called");


        // Lets use the existing PSC
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *migrationPSC = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];

        // Open the store
        id sourceStore = [migrationPSC addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[self localStoreURL] options:[self localStoreOptions] error:nil];

        if (!sourceStore) {

            FLOG(@" failed to add old store");
            migrationPSC = nil;
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            FLOG(@" Successfully added store to migrate");

            NSError *error;

            FLOG(@" About to migrate the store...");
            id migrationSuccess = [migrationPSC migratePersistentStore:sourceStore toURL:[self backupStoreURL] options:[self localStoreOptions] withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];

            if (migrationSuccess) {
                FLOG(@"store successfully backed up");
                migrationPSC = nil;
                // Now reset the backup preference
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:_makeBackupPreferenceKey];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                return TRUE;
            }
            else {
                FLOG(@"Failed to backup store: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                migrationPSC = nil;
                return FALSE;
            }

        }
        migrationPSC = nil;
        return FALSE;
    }

/**  Sets the selected file as the current store.
 Creates a backup of the current store first.

 @param fileURL The URL for the file to use.
 */
- (BOOL)restoreFile:(NSURL *)fileURL {
    FLOG(@" called");

    // Check if we are using iCloud
    if (_isCloudEnabled) {
        FLOG(@" using iCloud store so OK to restore");
        NSURL *currentURL = [self storeURL];
        FLOG(@" currentURL is %@", currentURL);

        FLOG(@" URL to use is %@", fileURL);

        [self saveContext];

        [self backupCurrentStoreWithNoCheck];

        // Close the current store and delete it
        _persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;
        _managedObjectContext = nil;

        [self removeICloudStore];

        [self moveStoreFileToICloud:fileURL delete:NO backup:NO];


    } else {
        FLOG(@" using local store so OK to restore");
        NSURL *currentURL = [self storeURL];
        FLOG(@" currentURL is %@", currentURL);

        FLOG(@" URL to use is %@", fileURL);

        [self saveContext];

        [self backupCurrentStoreWithNoCheck];

        // Close the current store and delete it
        _persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;
        _managedObjectContext = nil;

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

        // Delete the current store file
        if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:[currentURL path]]) {
            FLOG(@" target file exists");
            if (![fm removeItemAtURL:currentURL error:&error]) {
                FLOG(@" error unable to remove current store file");
                NSLog(@"Error removing item Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                FLOG(@" current store file removed");
            }
        }

        //
        //simply copy the file over
        BOOL copySuccess = [fm copyItemAtPath:[fileURL path]
                                       toPath:[currentURL path]
                                        error:&error];
        if (copySuccess) {
            FLOG(@" replaced current store file successfully");
            //[self postFileUpdateNotification];
        } else {
            FLOG(@"Error copying items Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Now open the store again

    [self openPersistentStore];

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How about the persistent store metadata? I've found out I'm loosing it after my *.sqlite database restored on other device. Is it true or my mistake?

Comment: This code is great. Thank you. I didn't see the option to backup the local store to iCloud though - can this be done fairly easily and would you recommend it? How would the code be altered - I know this is a lot more complex than making a backup to a local directory. I have the sample app so if there is a method I can add in there to backup the local store to iCloud Drive that would be great. I want to give the user the choice to upload to iCloud Drive or a local directory.

Comment: @kas-kad I am not sure about the metadata - I never worried about that in the sample code (or anywhere else for that matter).

Comment: @SAHM - It's been awhile since I looked at this code but as far as I can remember you can make a backup of the database to a local file and then separately copy that file to the iCloud container.  I thought there was code doing both the above in the sample applications at the above link.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald won't important WAL information be lost if migratePersistentStore is not used to copy the file to iCloud?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the persistent store is that you use (binary, SQLite, etc.); it is just a file on the filesystem.  You can make a copy of it whenever you want.

If you are using SQLite in iOS 7, be sure to make a copy of the other files associated with it as they are the journal files that go with it.  If you are using binary then there will be only a single file.

If you just copy the file there is no import step, you just copy it back to restore it.

There are more advanced designs such as exporting the entire database to something that is portable, such as JSON but that is a different subject.

### Update

> Well I've used the standard Xcode core data template, so according to the code I've just checked I'm using SQLite. So how do I find all related files? Or could you show me with some example code how to copy and insert back the files needed?

You use `NSFileManager` to copy the files.  You can look at the documents directory in your iOS simulator application to see the names of all the files.  Or you could use `NSFileManager` to scan the documents directory, find everything that starts with the same file name (`MyData.*` for example) and copy that into a back up directory.

As for sample code, no; it is only a couple of lines of code once you look at the documentation for `NSFileManager`.

Comment: Well I've used the standard Xcode core data template, so according to the code I've just checked I'm using SQLite. So how do I find all related files? Or could you show me with some example code how to copy and insert back the files needed?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How about the persistent store metadata? I've found out I'm loosing it after my *.sqlite database restored on other device. Is it true or my mistake?

Comment: If you are only copying the file then you should not be losing the metadata as it is stored in that file.  If you are doing an export/import then you would want to make sure you export the metadata as well.

Comment: Copying store that way during SQL transactions may be error prone. It's better to use `migratePersistentStore` and `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, also it's good to vacuum it afterwards before passing it to other device.

Comment: 'migratePersistentStore' removes the store from the coordinator after the migration so it is NOT a good replacement. If the copy of the store happens on the main thread there is very little risk of a sql operation occurring during the copy.

Comment: @Andy can you point to any examples of copying and vacuuming the store like you mentioned? But vacuum do you mean zip?

Comment: @SAHM `vacuum` means the packing of fragmented sqlite database. This normally decreases the file size and consolidates journal file. To do that you can initialize CoreData store with `NSSQLiteManualVacuumOption` option.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra You can create new PSC, add your main store as readonly, then migrate it to new place. Then it doesn't matter if it gets removed or not. You can also do `"journal_mode": @"DELETE"` during migration to get single SQLite file on the output. Journal can be added later.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra you definitely need to make sure that you do that orderly. That requires certain design of course but with journal mode I don't think you can safely copy SQLite store since it's few files, you can easily get inconsistent or corrupted store.

Comment: @Andy gotcha. Should the file be zipped as well? Would that be important to save space - or if we decide to email the backup file?

Comment: @SAHM You are certainly welcome to follow this advice but I would STRONGLY suggest you open your own question instead of continuing to hijacking this thread from 2014.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Often times when I do that, I get closed down for 'this question was already asked'. No win situation. Doing my best,

Comment: @SAHM In this case the original question was never marked as answered so you are in the clear :)

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579357/how-to-create-sharable-core-data-sqlite-backups-locally-and-in-icloud-using-cur

Answer (score 1):

I created the following method with the help of Apple sample [code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH23-SW1). This will take a backup of core data files and place it to the path that you want.

> Swift 5

```
/// Backing up store type to a new and unique location
/// The method is illustrated in the following code fragment, which shows how you can use migratePersistentStore to take a back up of a store and save it from one location to another.
/// If the old store type is XML, the example also converts the store to SQLite.
/// - Parameters:
///   - path: Where you want the backup to be done, please create a new unique directory with timestamp or the guid
///   - completion: Passes error in case of error or pass nil in case of success
class func backUpCoreDataFiles(path : URL, completion : @escaping (_ error : String?) -> ())
{

    // Every time new container is a must as migratePersistentStore method will loose the reference to the container on migration
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name : "<YourDataModelName>")
    container.loadPersistentStores
        { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error
            {
                fatalError("Failed to load store: \(error)")
            }
    }
    let coordinator = container.persistentStoreCoordinator
    let store = coordinator.persistentStores[0]
    do
    {
        try coordinator.migratePersistentStore(store, to : path, options : nil, withType : NSSQLiteStoreType)
        completion(nil)
    }
    catch
    {
        completion("\(Errors.coredataBackupError)\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```