# Back Up & Receive Core data SQlite3 database

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, sqlite

I want to  back up and retrieve sqlite3 database in core data. This is to provide a quick save and restore of users data saved in an app. The plan is to email the database, then open it on the receiving device and all the previously data will magically appear and all is good.

I have read many posts and documentation on the subject  but putting it all together is where I could do with some advice.

**What I have done so far:**

I have managed to email the `sqlite3`database using the following

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:0UL error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        DebugLog(@"Failed to read the file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        if (fileData == nil) {
            DebugLog(@"File data is nil");
        }
    }

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if (mailView != nil) {
        mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailView setSubject:@"back up database"];
        [mailView addAttachmentData:fileData
                           mimeType:@"application/octet-stream"
                           fileName:@"db.sqlite3"];

        [mailView setMessageBody:@"Database attached"
                          isHTML:NO];


        [self presentViewController:mailView animated:YES completion: NULL];

    }
```

Further research leads me to believe I have to attach other journal files to this to this? [iOS: How can I create a backup copy of my core data base? And how to export/import that copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151650/ios-how-can-i-create-a-backup-copy-of-my-core-data-base-and-how-to-export-impo)

Ive logged these documents as `db.sqlite db.sqlite-shm db.sqlite-wal`

My question is
1.  Do I send all these `db.sqlite db.sqlite-shm db.sqlite-wal` as attachments in the email? 
2.  What is the procedure to receive these files and copy them into the app.
Simply opening the attachment does not work as it can only be read by certain apps.  I then made a Document type in my info.plist and my app appears in the action sheet as an app to receive the document but crashes the app with error `incomprehensible archive`

So in summary, how can I save and restore my core data

Answer (score 0):

Archive all 3 sqlite files into one zip file and name it Backup.myappbackup or something similar (it’s good to add date of backup to filename). Than you can register extension to be recognized by your application which will allow Mail.app to recognize this extension and open this backup within your app. Next you will unarchive core data files, replace them at your locations and reconfigure core data stack. You can also allow users to put your backups through iTunes Sharing and restore it from your Documents folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sounds interesting...im going to try this as get back to you with some updated code if necessary. Could you explain a bit more on your suggestion of back ups though iTunes Sharing from the documents folder? Thanks

Comment: @JSA986 For iTunes Sharing see this http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app